# 403 ошибка при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, requests, bs4

```
    from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import time
import fake_useragent

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=121.100.19.195:8080")
options.add_argument("fake_useragent")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r"C:\Users\RB\Desktop\chromedriver.exe",
    options=options)

url = "https://partsouq.com/en/search/all?q="

f = open("SKU.txt", "r")
for i in f:
    responce = requests.get(url + i)
    print(responce)
```

В SKU.txt находятся 130702J203HAS 7538614902 130702J203HAS

проблема в том что при отправке запроса получаю

```
<Response [403]>
```

пробовал изменить несколько прокси, и менял user-agent

подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Comment: видимо ваш прокси требует авторизации

Comment: Используйте что то одно, selenium или requests. Cудя по коду я вам рекомендую использовать селенимум.

Comment: сайт не дает подключаться через селениум, появляется капча которая не закрывается, по этому хочу сначала настроить все так что бы появлялся Response [200], и потом уже работать с селениумом